# Incrementing (or decrementing) variable value per dataset in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have an Oracle query that uses `sysdate - N` to fetch info from `N` days ago. I would like to make a report that has, say, 3 datasets: `sysdate - N`, `sysdate - N - 1`, `sysdate - N - 2` using a variable in iReport. I am unclear on how to accomplish this. I believe the query should be exactly the same across all three datasets, but the value of the variable should increment by `1` each time, ie `sysdate - (N + 0)`, `sysdate - (N + 1)`, `sysdate - (N + 2)`. What type of incrementer do I need to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, jshin -- what do you want your output to look like? I'm pretty sure you can have 1 query and use groups to separate the data, but give us a little more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 SELECT DATECOL, COL1, COL2
 FROM THETABLE
 WHERE DATECOL BETWEEN (SYSDATE-($P{N}+0)) AND (SYSDATE-($P{N}+2))
 ORDER BY DATECOL
```

Then, in iReport, create a grouping band for DATECOL, and put COL1 and COL2 into your Detail 1 band. That will separate the results for each time period.

Comment: I'm new to reporting software and didn't understand what the bands actually meant. That makes sense. Thank you

Comment: One thing to remember is that the bands don't group the way a SQL query groups. If you need to perform grouping in your query for aggregate functions, continue to do that. Also make sure that your output is in order. In the example above, if there were multiple records for each DATECOL value and the dates were not in order, you might see multiple bands for each DATECOL value as iReport iterates through the data and encounters changes in the date values. That might make more sense after you create the band and see it in action.